# Why can't I get parameters to work with apply-templates in XSL?

Tags: xslt, parameters

I am finding it impossible to get with-param to work with apply-templates. As an example, I've hacked the examples given in [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_apply_templates.asp).

xsl

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:with-param name="test" select="'has this parameter been passed?'"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cd">
  <xsl:param name="test"></xsl:param>
  parameter:
  <xsl:value-of select="$test"></xsl:value-of>
</xsl:template>
```

xml

```
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

(Hopefully) you'll see that the test parameter is not being passed to the cd template. I can get it to work when using call-template, but not apply-templates. What's going on? I am using XSL 1.0. Please ignore the fact that I'm passing a hard-coded parameter - this is just an example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hmmm... interesting... fails for me using `XslTransform` and `XslCompiledTransform` in .NET - but it looks like it *should* work... curious...

**update** the problem seesm to be the **root** match; try

```
<xsl:template match="/catalog"> <!-- CHANGE HERE --> 
  <xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:with-param name="test" select="'has this parameter been passed?'"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

This then works for me without any other changes. The difference is that you were matching the root node. When you did your "apply templates", it cascaded *first* to catalog (with the param), *then* to cd (without the param). To get what you want, you need to start at catalog. You can see this by adding an `<xsl:vaue-of select="name()"/>` to the match, and then try it as "/" and "/catalog".

Comment: Ahh. But why doesn't the parameter get passed to cd?

Comment: catalog is the root here, so the original example should work. And it does with libXSLT and Opera.

Comment: "should" and "does"... don't always agree with each-other ;-p

Comment: @darasd - re the "why": because the default match is simply something like <apply-templates select="*"/>

Answer (score 2):

Try specifying templates to apply:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="catalog/cd">
    <xsl:with-param name="test" select="'has this parameter been passed?'"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: didn't catch that - try this solution. It seems something goes awry when not specifying the templates path.

Comment: yes, you are right. Howver, I believe that having // in the select is bad form. Furthermore, It seems that this double slash is crutial to passing parameters. In my real code, I was already passing a node in the select, however, the parameter was only passed after prefixing the node with //. WHY?

Comment: Ok - now SO is behaving strange - this question does not have 4 answers also your edits get shown and then get lost randomly...

Comment: I removed my original comment, as it no longer applied after you edited your answer!

Comment: Use Marc Gravell solution - I'm not sure why it should make a difference though - apply templates should work in all cases. Specifying catalog/cd instead of //cd works for me as well.

Comment: Sorry Goran; I thought I had it cracked, but I was wrong, so I rolled back an update. My bad - sorry for any confusion. And it does have 4 answers... if you have 10k+ rep ;-p (one is deleted)

Comment: I meant Marc Gravell answer was changing on every refresh... seems ok now

Comment: ah ok - will start deleting my comments soon :)

Answer (score 2):

you could always go with xsl:call-template.. eg:

```
...
<xsl:call-template name="foo">
   <xsl:with-param name="bars" select="42"/>
</xsl:call-template>
...

<xsl:template name="foo">
   <xsl:param name="bars"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="$node"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me with libxslt 1.1.24 from http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/
  :

```
$ xsltproc xml1.xsl xml1.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>


  parameter:
  has this parameter been passed?

  parameter:
  has this parameter been passed?
```

Comment: interesting. I am using MSXML 4.0. However, it also fails to work when I view it in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem is that there is no match for *cd* element under root. Under root you have *catalog* element not a *cd* element, so modify the template to match='catalog'